# removing bigrams that contain common stopwords

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

I have a function as below. It returns all bigrams and trigram in a sentence. I would like to keep only bigrams and trigrams that dont contain any stopwords. How could I use `from nltk.copus import stopwords` to do the same?

I know how to remove remove stopwords before creating bigrams and trigrams. But I would like to remove stopwords after creating bigrams and trigrams.

```
from nltk import everygrams
from nltk.copus import stopwords


def clean_text_function2(text):
    t = text #contractions.fix(text)
    t= t.lower().split()#lower case
    t = [(re.sub(r'[^a-z ]', '', ch)) for ch in t]#remove everything other than a-z
    #t=[word for word in t if word not in stopword]#removing stop words
    t= [wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in t]
    t=[snowball_stemmer.stem(word) for word in t]
    t=(' ').join(t)
    t=list(everygrams(t.split(), 2, 3))
    return t






print (clean_text_function2("i love when it rains a lot and brings temperature down"))

[('i', 'love'), ('love', 'when'), ('when', 'it'), ('it', 'rain'), ('rain', 'a'), ('a', 'lot'), ('lot', 'and'), ('and', 'bring'), ('bring', 'temperatur'), ('temperatur', 'down'), ('i', 'love', 'when'), ('love', 'when', 'it'), ('when', 'it', 'rain'), ('it', 'rain', 'a'), ('rain', 'a', 'lot'), ('a', 'lot', 'and'), ('lot', 'and', 'bring'), ('and', 'bring', 'temperatur'), ('bring', 'temperatur', 'down')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a filter, keeping only the tuples that have no stop words.  I'll be overly verbose to make sure the technique is readable.

For each gram, use `any` to check for any of the given stop words.

```
grams = [('i', 'love'), ('love', 'when'), ('when', 'it'), ('it', 'rain'), ('rain', 'a'), ('a', 'lot'), ('lot', 'and'), ('and', 'bring'), ('bring', 'temperatur'), ('temperatur', 'down'), ('i', 'love', 'when'), ('love', 'when', 'it'), ('when', 'it', 'rain'), ('it', 'rain', 'a'), ('rain', 'a', 'lot'), ('a', 'lot', 'and'), ('lot', 'and', 'bring'), ('and', 'bring', 'temperatur'), ('bring', 'temperatur', 'down')]
stops = ["a", "and", "it", "the"]

clean = [gram for gram in grams if not any(stop in gram for stop in stops)]
print(clean)
```

Output:

```
[('i', 'love'), ('love', 'when'), ('bring', 'temperatur'), ('temperatur', 'down'), ('i', 'love', 'when'), ('bring', 'temperatur', 'down')]
```